# join 3 tables in linq getting all entries from two tables

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have 3 tables

- A project table
- A product table
- An update table

The product table holds different products from a project, and the update table holds updates made to various products and holds a reference to the user who did it.

Basically what I want is to have a query that returns all products (since products to projects is a many to one relation) ordered by the date they we're last updated by the user who is currently logged in.

This is my current query:

```
IEnumerable<ProjectProduct> list =
       from joined in
           (from product in db.GetTable<Product>()
            join project in db.GetTable<Project>()
            on product.ProjectId equals project.ID
            select new { product, project })
       join projectupd in db.GetTable<ProjectUpdate>()
       on joined.product.ID equals projectupd.ProductID
       where projectupd.CreatedBy == ParamUser
       orderby projectupd.LastUpdate
       select new ProjectProduct(joined.project, joined.product);
```

However, the result I'm getting is only the entries in the update table, and not all the existing products. I know that the "where" clause makes it only select the updates created by a specific user, so I'm on the right track, but I have tried a couple of things to make the query successful, without luck though.

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to get the desired result?

Comment: have you tried the same query in sql to verify that you would get the results you are expecting?

Comment: What are you expecting to do if the user never updated the product?

Comment: Have your entities got navigation properties?

Comment: I am expecting to get all the entries from projects and products, but I am only getting that one entry in the updates table I made
bob it's a test database and I should get more than just one entry(the entry I put into the update table) so I am sure that I need to alter that query

in other words, I need all entries in projects and products, but the ones that we're last updated should be the first entries in the results, not the only entries in the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer that's a little verbose, and it uses method-chain syntax, but I do think it does what your looking for:

```
var products = db.GetTable<Product>();
var projects = db.GetTable<Project>();
var projectUpdates = db.GetTable<ProjectUpdate>();

var latestProjectUpdatesForUser = projectUpdates
    .Where(x => x.CreatedBy == paramUser)
    .GroupBy(x => x.ProductId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastUpdate).First());

var list = products
    .Join(
        projects,
        product => product.ProjectId,
        project => project.Id,
        (product, project) => new
            {
                Product = product,
                Project = project,
                Update = latestProjectUpdatesForUser.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ProductId == product.Id)
            }
    )
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Update != null ? (DateTime?)x.Update.LastUpdate : null)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Project.Id)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Product.Id)
    .Select(x => new ProjectProduct { Project = x.Project, Product = x.Product});
```

It takes advantage of the fact that `DateTime?` is sortable and that `null` values end up last when using `OrderByDescending`.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @user1617103. Thanks for the accept. Yes, you need 15 rep to upvote. Why don't you come back later when you have the necessary rep? :-) And you should edit your [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1617103) and change the default user name to your real name, or a nickname if you so choose.